# Same recovery phrase to two wallets?

Tags: blockchain.info

I created a bitcoin wallet on blockchain.info From my understanding, if I lose my account or if blockchain.info stops offering a wallet service (this probably wont happen, but just for the sake of my curiosity, lets pretend it does)I can use my recovery phrase to get my bitcoins to another wallet. How would I do it? Is this phrase the same as a private key? If not can I convert this phrase to a private key? Also, I have two wallets under my blockchain.info account, would the phrase recover both wallet's bitcoins or would it just merge all bitcoins into one wallet? Would I still use the same recovery sentence in case the same issue happens again?

Oh and by the way, I read somewhere that there are different wallets or phrases (BIP39, BIP32/44 or something like that) can someone explain that aswell?

Answer (score 1):

blockchain.info's recovery phrase is a BIP 39 phrase. They use BIP 32 derivation and BIP 44 derivation paths IIRC. This means that you can use the recovery phrase to import your blockchain.info wallet into any other wallet that also support BIPs 32, 39, and 44. Since it uses BIP 32, you will have access to all of the private keys that you used on blockchain.info.

Comment: This answer is helpful, but I'm not sure if it fully answers the original post, because it also asks about two wallets within the same blockchain.info account. I asked a similar question with more details: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/58928/blockchain-info-does-recovery-phrase-recover-all-wallets