# How can I migrate from blockchain wallet to Electrum?

Tags: wallet, electrum

I would appreciate a simple step-by-step guide to migrate from Blockchain wallet (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=piuk.blockchain.android) to Electrum wallet. Presumably I would have to use my blockchain.info wallet seed words to create a new Electrum wallet. Is there a step-by-step guide for this operation?

Thanks

P.S. I am not allowed to use "migration" and also "Blockchain Wallet" tags because I am a newbie

Answer (score 4):

These steps are for new Blockchain.info wallets based of BIP39 seeds.
If you have previously imported private keys to blockchain.info they have to be exported separately, as they are not part of the keys derived from the seed.

1. Get your blockchain.info seed. Login to your blockchain.info account, click on 'Security Center' then click on 'Backup Phrase'. Be aware that onced the phrase is backed up, you won't be able to access it again on blockchain.info. So note it down carefully.
2. Start Electrum, choose to restore a standard wallet, then restore from seed, enter your seed, then click options and check the 'BIP39 seed' box. -> Click Ok/Next.
3. [Blockchain.info follows the BIP 44 standard for derivation paths, so the default account has a derivation path m/44'/0'/0'/0](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/58928/blockchain-info-does-recovery-phrase-recover-all-wallets)
4. You should now have migrated to Electrum.

Comment: Is Blockchain.info Wallet the same as Blockchain Wallet? What I have is the second one. Also after the BIP39 choice there is one final option as described in this video guide https://youtu.be/E-KcY6KUVnY (for Multibit). How should I set the final one in the case of Blockchain Wallet?

Comment: Added an extra step.   Blockchain Wallet, you mean like Bitcoin Core? Which software/exchange did you get your wallet from?

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. I will try it. My wallet is this: : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=piuk.blockchain.android

Comment: I do your tutorial step by step 1-2-3-4 But in electrum wallet, I don't see my coins :/ How long need to wait what coins to show in Electrum? I wait for 1h. Or maybe need to configure Electrum? Thank you!

Comment: @Thomas they should show up immediately, maybe you got an old blockchain.info wallet?

Comment: @Thomas make sure to set the correct derivation path as you may have multiple wallets. You can also refer to https://blog.blockonomics.co/how-to-restore-blockchain-com-wallet-into-electrum-f593ec79ab3d