# Blockchain wallet showing 0 however app showing balance

Tags: blockchain, fraud

So my blockchain desktop wallet is showing 0 balance whoever if o go in to the app i can see my bitcoin wallet balance. When again i click on the wallet it goes back to 0 in the app for some reason. Then if i go in to transfer within the blockachain app, my balance is shown in ROI Bitcoin. I try to send From Roi to my BTC wallet and it also shows my total spendable balance but once i want to proceed after following the recomended fee by the app i get this typ of error message *Transaction Failed*, i then clock on the info and it comes up with *Attempt to invoke virtual method intjava.lang.string.length() on null object reference*.
I have now run out of options and what is the most suspicious for me is that Blockchain support have been responding to my emails and have been asking me for different screenshots which sounded as they were actually investigating this however now they have just been ghosting me for weeks, If i submitt a new support ticket they respond but then again after realising its me again they ignore any of my emails.

Please can you someone came across this situation where Wallet balance was showing the amount within the App as ROI but werent able to use the coins and in the desktop app it is balance 0 ?

I litteraly do know who to go to since support are ignoring me.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a note of your "backup phrase"? (never tell any helper what it is, but you should have this somewhere safe).

Comment: Yes i do have that

Comment: Does the app (on your phone) use the exact same 12 word backup phrase as your desktop wallet?

Comment: I believe so, how can i find out ?

Comment: https://support.blockchain.com/hc/en-us/articles/208771356-How-do-I-make-a-wallet-backup-  Obviously I'd be very careful doing this. I'd only do it somewhere private with no distractions, no one else around, no time pressure, with pen and paper handy and somewhere safe to put the paper

Comment: Yes i have done that

Comment: So they are the same?

Comment: I didnt have the backup phrase until today, so i did it on my PC and now when i look in to the app it shows complete hence i believe whatever i did on PC has an effect on the app hence they should be the same

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "ROI"?

Comment: Ao i open my blockchain app, i see the balance i then click on to send, then under * send crypto, select the wallet you want to send from* it says ROI bitcoin and then the balance...

Answer (score 0):

If Blockchain support are not able to help you and you have the 12-word "backup phrase" I believe the best course of action is to migrate to a new wallet.

By migrate wallets I mean use your backup phrase with wallet software written by a different organisation. The only important thing stored in a wallet is the private key generated from the backup phrase (also referred to as a seed phrase or recovery phrase). So any wallet that contains that key can be used to spend money that has been received at addresses created from that key.

If you are a frequent user of Blockchain's other services, such as buying and selling Bitcoin or other cryptocurrency trading, you might not want to do this. However there are alternative exchanges that you could use instead.

There are several wallets that have a much better reputation than the Blockchain wallets.

For example see ...

- [How can I migrate from blockchain wallet to Electrum?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/66601/13866)

As well as the backup phrase, you need to know the "derivation path" for your old wallet. The accepted answer to the linked question assumes a derivation path of `m/44'/0'/0'/0`.

Instead of *importing* the key to a new type of wallet, it can be safer to *sweep* the keys into a new type of wallet. Sweeping just means using the old key in a new wallet to create a Bitcoin transaction that transfers the money to the control of a new key in the new wallet. If you ever *imported* additional private-keys into the old wallet you'd also have to either repeat that and import those extra keys to the new wallet or instead sweep those keys into the new wallet. Given your situation I would not sweep any keys at all until certain of the derivation path of your old wallet, it would be safest to first try importing the keys using the backup phrase and, once everything is working, then move the money to new keys.

If all this seems too complicated, you might reasonably conclude that Bitcoin is not for you.

Comment: Yes this all makes sense and it does sound tok complicated all i want is to withdraw the amount i have there and thats it however i am unable to as blockchain wallet is showing different amounts every time and the most confusing thing is it shows balance there but when i want to transfer it gives me an error message saying unsuficient funds...and desktop showing 0 but app showing the balance in ROI..

Comment: @Tami: ROI usually means "Return on Investment" and so may be just some historical note about profitability of some trading activity in the past. It might not represent current balance. "Insufficient funds" means you either have no money or don't have enough to cover both the amount you are withdrawing and the necessary transaction fee.